# convert pinelineRDD to datafame in pyspark via list?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I try to load a comma delimited csv file into RSD but it gives me pipelinedRSD
and I try to convert to a proper dataframe.

csv file has format

```
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,1,4.0,964982703
1,3,4.0,964981247
1,6,4.0,964982224
1,47,5.0,964983815
1,50,5.0,964982931
1,70,3.0,964982400
```

Whats the easiest way to do that? I am using pyspark 3.3 python 3.9.12

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///sparkCourse/ml-latest-small/ratings.csv")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])

lines2=lines.collect()

type(lines2) #list

#['userId,movieId,rating,timestamp',
# '1,1,4.0,964982703',
# '1,3,4.0,964981247',
# '1,6,4.0,964982224',
# '1,47,5.0,964983815']
```

Comment: the csv file can be directly read into a dataframe using `spark.read.csv(<path>, header=True)`. why are you going the RDD route?

Comment: I am following an udemy class which is 2017 version I do have another person load directly into dataframe but I like to see how RDD works.

Comment: the elements in `lines2` are strings and not strings separated by commas. e.g., `'s,t,r,i,n,g'` is what you have, not `'s','t','r','i','n','g'`. are you sure this is what you want?